# Video.js not playing m3u8 video on latest version

Tags: next.js, html5-video, http-live-streaming, video.js, m3u8

I am using `video.js` npm library for my `next.js` project. My video.js component is given below and it will be having the videos in `m3u8` formats.

on my localhost, it sometimes shows the video, sometimes doesn't show. It loads at first the control bar and big play btn is displayed, but then in a second, it disappears and gives the error as

> The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

I am using the latest version already for video.js which has VHS support and HLS support. version is `"^7.18.1"`

```
return (
<div data-vjs-player>
  <video
    id={id}
    ref={videoRef}
    className="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
    poster={poster}
    autoPlay={false}
  >
    <source src={src} type="video/mp4" />
    <source src={src} type="application/x-mpegURL" />
    <source src={src} type="video/webm" />
    <p className="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      {' '}
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">supports HTML5 video.</a>
    </p>
  </video>
</div>
);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was with back-end. back-end needs to add CORS settings to make it work.